Retrieving control flow graph using opt in Clang 19 produces -opaque-pointers issues
I wanted to use opt to get the control flow graph of a C code, using clang 18. It does not work, saying some issues with-opaque-pointers. Any idea?
root@2f18de92db5f:/# cat example.c
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        printf("Positive\n");
    } else {
        printf("Non-positive\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    foo(10);
    foo(-5);
    return 0;
}


root@2f18de92db5f:/# clang -S -emit-llvm example.c -o example.ll
root@2f18de92db5f:/# opt -dot-cfg example.ll
example.ll:12:17: warning: ptr type is only supported in -opaque-pointers mode
  store i32 %0, ptr %2, align 4
                ^
opt: example.ll:12:17: error: expected type
  store i32 %0, ptr %2, align 4


Your opt version is not 18. With opt-18, this is the output for the command you are running:
$ opt --version
Homebrew LLVM version 18.1.8
  Optimized build.
  Default target: arm64-apple-darwin23.5.0
  Host CPU: apple-m1

$ opt -dot-cfg example.ll
opt: Unknown command line argument '-dot-cfg'.  Try: 'opt --help'
opt: Did you mean '--dot-dom'?

$ opt -passes=dot-cfg example.ll
WARNING: You're attempting to print out a bitcode file.
This is inadvisable as it may cause display problems. If
you REALLY want to taste LLVM bitcode first-hand, you
can force output with the `-f' option.

Writing '.foo.dot'...
Writing '.main.dot'...


With the new pass manager, the passes should be invoked with -passes=<pass-pipeline>.
